# How to re-design this firebase database to use minimal classes?

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a newbie to Firebase. And I've set up my database, and its working fine. However, there are some issues. My database as JSON is provided below. Kindly have a look at it.

```
    {
  "Cohesion" : 
  {
    "Situational" : 
    {
      "Home" : 
      {
        "Chelsea" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 4,
          "Penalty" : 1,
          "Set_Piece" : 0,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Liverpool" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 4,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 0,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Burnley" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 3,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 0,
          "Own_goal" : 0          
        },
        "Arsenal" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 2,
          "Penalty" : 1,
          "Set_Piece" : 2,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Watford" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 2,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 0,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "West_Ham" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 2,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 1,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Bournemouth" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 2,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 0,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Manchester_City" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 2,
          "Penalty" : 1,
          "Set_Piece" : 1,
          "Own_goal" : 1
        },
        "Southampton" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 1,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 1,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Middlesbrough" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 1,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 1,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Leicester" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 1,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 1,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Swansea" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 1,
          "Penalty" : 1,
          "Set_Piece" : 0,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Sunderland" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 1,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 0,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Tottenham" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 1,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 1,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Crystal_Palace" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 1,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 0,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Manchester_United" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 1,
          "Penalty" : 1,
          "Set_Piece" : 1,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Hull" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" :1,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 1,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "West_Bromwich_Albion" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 0,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 1,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Stoke" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 0,
          "Penalty" : 1,  
          "Set_Piece" : 0,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Everton" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 0,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 1,
          "Own_goal" : 1
        }
      },
      "Away" :
      {
        "Chelsea" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 1,
          "Open_Play" : 3,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 0,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Liverpool" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 3,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 1,
          "Own_goal" : 1
        },
        "Burnley" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 0,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 0,
          "Own_goal" : 0          
        },
        "Arsenal" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 2,
          "Penalty" : 1,
          "Set_Piece" : 0,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Watford" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 5,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 0,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "West_Ham" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 1,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 1,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Bournemouth" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 0,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 1,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Manchester_City" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 4,
          "Penalty" : 1,
          "Set_Piece" : 1,
          "Own_goal" : 1
        },
        "Southampton" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 0,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 0,
          "Own_goal" : 1
        },
        "Middlesbrough" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 2,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 0,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Leicester" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 1,
          "Penalty" : 1,
          "Set_Piece" : 0,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Swansea" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 2,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 0,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Sunderland" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 1,
          "Penalty" : 1,
          "Set_Piece" : 0,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Tottenham" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 1,
          "Open_Play" : 4,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 1,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Crystal_Palace" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 2,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 0,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Manchester_United" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 4,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 0,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Hull" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" :1,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 2,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "West_Bromwich_Albion" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 0,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 1,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Stoke" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 0,
          "Penalty" : 0,  
          "Set_Piece" : 1,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        },
        "Everton" : 
        {
          "Counter_Attack" : 0,
          "Open_Play" : 4,
          "Penalty" : 0,
          "Set_Piece" : 1,
          "Own_goal" : 0
        }

      }
    },
    "Summary" : {
      "Arsenal" : 7.02,
      "Bournemouth" : 6.67,
      "Burnley" : 6.71,
      "Chelsea" : 6.92,
      "Crystal_Palace" : 6.88,
      "Everton" : 7.12,
      "Hull" : 7.04,
      "Leicester" : 6.6,
      "Liverpool" : 6.87,
      "Manchester_City" : 7.06,
      "Manchester_United" : 7.043,
      "Middlesbrough" : 6.82,
      "Southampton" : 6.57,
      "Stoke" : 6.55,
      "Sunderland" : 6.52,
      "Swansea" : 6.83,
      "Tottenham" : 7.01,
      "Watford" : 6.7,
      "West_Bromwich_Albion" : 6.73,
      "West_Ham" : 6.74
    },
    "Shots" : 
    {
      "Arsenal" :
        {
          "Total" : 13.0,
          "OffTarget" : 5.0,
          "OnTarget" : 3.5
        },

        "Bournemouth" :
        {
          "Total" : 10.5,
          "OffTarget" : 3.5,
          "OnTarget" : 4.0
        },

        "Burnley" :
        {
          "Total" : 8.7,
          "OffTarget" : 4.0,
          "OnTarget" : 2.3
        },

        "Chelsea" :
        {
          "Total" : 19.0,
          "OffTarget" : 6.5,
          "OnTarget" : 8.0
        },

        "Crystal_Palace" :
        {
          "Total" : 19.0,
          "OffTarget" : 9.5,
          "OnTarget" : 4.5
        },

        "Everton" :
        {
          "Total" : 16.5,
          "OffTarget" : 5.5,
          "OnTarget" : 7.5
        },

        "Hull" :
        {
          "Total" : 11.0,
          "OffTarget" : 5.5,
          "OnTarget" : 3.5
        },

        "Leicester" :
        {
          "Total" : 10.5,
          "OffTarget" : 3.5,
          "OnTarget" : 3.5
        },

        "Liverpool" :
        {
          "Total" : 17.0,
          "OffTarget" : 2.0,
          "OnTarget" : 11.0

        },

        "Manchester_City" :
        {
          "Total" : 19.0,
          "OffTarget" : 9.0,
          "OnTarget" : 4.5
        },

        "Manchester_United" :
        {
          "Total" : 13.0,
          "OffTarget" : 6.0,
          "OnTarget" : 4
        },

        "Middlesbrough" :
        {
          "Total" : 12.0,
          "OffTarget" : 5.5,
          "OnTarget" : 3.0
        },

        "Southampton" :
        {
          "Total" : 20.0,
          "OffTarget" : 7.5,
          "OnTarget" : 6.5
        },

        "Stoke" :
        {
          "Total" : 12.0,
          "OffTarget" : 5.0,
          "OnTarget" : 2.5
        },

        "Sunderland" :
        {
          "Total" : 14.5,
          "OffTarget" : 3.5,
          "OnTarget" : 3.5
        },

        "Swansea" :
        {
          "Total" : 14.5,
          "OffTarget" : 7.5,
          "OnTarget" : 2.5
        },

        "Tottenham" :
        {
          "Total" : 15.5,
          "OffTarget" : 7.0,
          "OnTarget" : 4.5
        },

        "Watford" :
        {
          "Total" : 10.0,
          "OffTarget" : 4.0,
          "OnTarget" : 4.0
        },

        "West_Bromwich_Albion" :
        {
          "Total" : 12.0,
          "OffTarget" : 5.5,
          "OnTarget" : 3.0
        },

        "West_Ham" :
        {
          "Total" : 17.5,
          "OffTarget" : 10.0,
          "OnTarget" : 3.0
        }

    },
    "Passes" :
    {
      "Home" :
      {
        "Arsenal" :
        {
          "Cross" : 24,
          "ThroughBall" : 4,
          "LongBall" : 51,
          "ShortPass" : 489 
        },

        "Bournemouth" :
        {
          "Cross" : 26,
          "ThroughBall" : 1,
          "LongBall" : 65,
          "ShortPass" : 420
        },

        "Burnley" :
        {
          "Cross" : 15,
          "ThroughBall" : 0,
          "LongBall" : 77,
          "ShortPass" : 245
        },

        "Chelsea" :
        {
          "Cross" : 23,
          "ThroughBall" : 2,
          "LongBall" : 70,
          "ShortPass" : 527
        },

        "Crystal_Palace" :
        {
          "Cross" : 36,
          "ThroughBall" : 0,
          "LongBall" : 82,
          "ShortPass" : 356
        },

        "Everton" :
        {
          "Cross" : 16,
          "ThroughBall" : 1,
          "LongBall" : 75,
          "ShortPass" : 355
        },

        "Hull" :
        {
          "Cross" : 11,
          "ThroughBall" : 2,
          "LongBall" : 86,
          "ShortPass" : 336
        },

        "Leicester" :
        {
          "Cross" : 17,
          "ThroughBall" : 1,
          "LongBall" : 73,
          "ShortPass" : 315
        },

        "Liverpool" :
        {
          "Cross" : 7,
          "ThroughBall" : 3,
          "LongBall" : 75,
          "ShortPass" : 534
        },

        "Manchester_City" :
        {
          "Cross" : 20,
          "ThroughBall" : 4,
          "LongBall" : 56,
          "ShortPass" : 579
        },

        "Manchester_United" :
        {
          "Cross" : 22,
          "ThroughBall" : 1,
          "LongBall" : 57,
          "ShortPass" : 341
        },

        "Middlesbrough" :
        {
          "Cross" : 28,
          "ThroughBall" : 0,
          "LongBall" : 74,
          "ShortPass" : 368
        },

        "Southampton" :
        {
          "Cross" : 26,
          "ThroughBall" : 3,
          "LongBall" : 51,
          "ShortPass" : 486
        },

        "Stoke" :
        {
          "Cross" : 20,
          "ThroughBall" : 1,
          "LongBall" : 67,
          "ShortPass" : 283
        },

        "Sunderland" :
        {
          "Cross" : 17,
          "ThroughBall" : 2,
          "LongBall" : 54,
          "ShortPass" : 291
        },

        "Swansea" :
        {
          "Cross" : 27,
          "ThroughBall" : 0,
          "LongBall" : 51,
          "ShortPass" : 437
        },

        "Tottenham" :
        {
          "Cross" : 20,
          "ThroughBall" : 2,
          "LongBall" : 76,
          "ShortPass" : 361
        },

        "Watford" :
        {
          "Cross" : 20,
          "ThroughBall" : 1,
          "LongBall" : 68,
          "ShortPass" : 305
        },

        "West_Bromwich_Albion" :
        {
          "Cross" : 20,
          "ThroughBall" : 0,
          "LongBall" : 67,
          "ShortPass" : 253
        },

        "West_Ham" :
        {
          "Cross" : 24,
          "ThroughBall" : 1,
          "LongBall" : 58,
          "ShortPass" : 345 
        }

      },

      "Away" :
      {
        "Arsenal" :
        {
          "Cross" : 19,
          "ThroughBall" : 5,
          "LongBall" : 55,
          "ShortPass" : 474
        },

        "Bournemouth" :
        {
          "Cross" : 14,
          "ThroughBall" : 2,
          "LongBall" : 76,
          "ShortPass" : 296
        },

        "Burnley" :
        {
          "Cross" : 20,
          "ThroughBall" : 0,
          "LongBall" : 54,
          "ShortPass" : 365
        },

        "Chelsea" :
        {
          "Cross" : 24,
          "ThroughBall" : 2,
          "LongBall" : 55,
          "ShortPass" : 474
        },

        "Crystal_Palace" :
        {
          "Cross" : 24,
          "ThroughBall" : 1,
          "LongBall" : 73,
          "ShortPass" : 287
        },

        "Everton" :
        {
          "Cross" : 19,
          "ThroughBall" : 2,
          "LongBall" : 79,
          "ShortPass" : 500
        },

        "Hull" :
        {
          "Cross" : 16,
          "ThroughBall" : 3,
          "LongBall" : 84,
          "ShortPass" : 460
        },

        "Leicester" :
        {
          "Cross" : 17,
          "ThroughBall" : 1,
          "LongBall" : 67,
          "ShortPass" : 339
        },

        "Liverpool" :
        {
          "Cross" : 17,
          "ThroughBall" : 2,
          "LongBall" : 66,
          "ShortPass" : 528
        },

        "Manchester_City" :
        {
          "Cross" : 15,
          "ThroughBall" : 5,
          "LongBall" : 63,
          "ShortPass" : 482
        },

        "Manchester_United" :
        {
          "Cross" : 24,
          "ThroughBall" : 1,
          "LongBall" : 61,
          "ShortPass" : 531
        },

        "Middlesbrough" :
        {
          "Cross" : 13,
          "ThroughBall" : 3,
          "LongBall" : 90,
          "ShortPass" : 407
        },

        "Southampton" :
        {
          "Cross" : 20,
          "ThroughBall" : 1,
          "LongBall" : 72,
          "ShortPass" : 427
        },

        "Stoke" :
        {
          "Cross" : 20,
          "ThroughBall" : 1,
          "LongBall" : 56,
          "ShortPass" : 357
        },

        "Sunderland" :
        {
          "Cross" : 18,
          "ThroughBall" : 2,
          "LongBall" : 62,
          "ShortPass" : 171
        },

        "Swansea" :
        {
          "Cross" : 26,
          "ThroughBall" : 0,
          "LongBall" : 67,
          "ShortPass" : 314
        },

        "Tottenham" :
        {
          "Cross" : 20,
          "ThroughBall" : 0,
          "LongBall" : 78,
          "ShortPass" : 423
        },

        "Watford" :
        {
          "Cross" : 14,
          "ThroughBall" : 1,
          "LongBall" : 72,
          "ShortPass" : 258
        },

        "West_Bromwich_Albion" :
        {
          "Cross" : 19,
          "ThroughBall" : 1,
          "LongBall" : 81,
          "ShortPass" : 182
        },

        "West_Ham" :
        {
          "Cross" : 13,
          "ThroughBall" : 1,
          "LongBall" : 83,
          "ShortPass" : 235
        }

      }
    },

    "Recent" :
    {
      "Manchester_City" :
      {
        "Game1" : 1,
        "Game2" : 1,
        "Game3" : 1,
        "Game4" : 1,
        "Game5" : 1
      },

      "Everton" :
      {
        "Game1" : 0,
        "Game2" : 1,
        "Game3" : 1,
        "Game4" : 1,
        "Game5" : 1
      },

      "Tottenham" :
      {
        "Game1" : 0,
        "Game2" : 1,
        "Game3" : 0,
        "Game4" : 1,
        "Game5" : 1
      },

      "Arsenal" :
      {
        "Game1" : -1,
        "Game2" : 0,
        "Game3" : 1,
        "Game4" : 1,
        "Game5" : 1
      },

      "Chelsea" :
      {
        "Game1" : 1,
        "Game2" : 1,
        "Game3" : 1,
        "Game4" : 0,
        "Game5" : 1
      },

      "Liverpool" :
      {
        "Game1" : 1,
        "Game2" : -1,
        "Game3" : 0,
        "Game4" : 1,
        "Game5" : 1
      },

      "Manchester_United" :
      {
        "Game1" : 1,
        "Game2" : 1,
        "Game3" : 1,
        "Game4" : -1,
        "Game5" : -1
      },

      "Crystal_Palace" :
      {
        "Game1" : -1,
        "Game2" : -1,
        "Game3" : 0,
        "Game4" : 1,
        "Game5" : 1
      },

      "Watford" :
      {
        "Game1" : 0,
        "Game2" : -1,
        "Game3" : -1,
        "Game4" : 1,
        "Game5" : 1
      },

      "West_Bromwich_Albion" :
      {
        "Game1" : 1,
        "Game2" : -1,
        "Game3" : 0,
        "Game4" : -1,
        "Game5" : 1
      },

      "Leicester" :
      {
        "Game1" : -1,
        "Game2" : 0,
        "Game3" : 1,
        "Game4" : -1,
        "Game5" : 1
      },

      "Hull" :
      {
        "Game1" : 1,
        "Game2" : 1,
        "Game3" : -1,
        "Game4" : 0,
        "Game5" : -1
      },

      "Middlesbrough" :
      {
        "Game1" : 0,
        "Game2" : 1,
        "Game3" : 0,
        "Game4" : -1,
        "Game5" : -1
      },

      "Southampton" :
      {
        "Game1" : 0,
        "Game2" : -1,
        "Game3" : 0,
        "Game4" : -1,
        "Game5" : 1
      },

      "Swansea" :
      {
        "Game1" : 1,
        "Game2" : -1,
        "Game3" : -1,
        "Game4" : 0,
        "Game5" : -1
      },

      "Burnley" :
      {
        "Game1" : -1,
        "Game2" : 1,
        "Game3" : -1,
        "Game4" : 0,
        "Game5" : -1
      },

      "Bournemouth" :
      {
        "Game1" : -1,
        "Game2" : -1,
        "Game3" : 0,
        "Game4" : 1,
        "Game5" : -1
      },

      "West_Ham" :
      {
        "Game1" : -1,
        "Game2" : 1,
        "Game3" : -1,
        "Game4" : -1,
        "Game5" : -1
      },

      "Sunderland" :
      {
        "Game1" : -1,
        "Game2" : -1,
        "Game3" : 0,
        "Game4" : -1,
        "Game5" : -1
      },

      "Stoke" :
      {
        "Game1" : 0,
        "Game2" : -1,
        "Game3" : -1,
        "Game4" : -1,
        "Game5" : -1
      }
    },
    "Head2Head" :
    {

    }
  }
}
```

This is a database that consist the data of English premier league teams. Now since Firebase uses Jackson to deserialize JSON, I have a big issue here, I'd need to create lot many classes to access these data, So one solution I was thinking was to club as many values possible under one club name, which is repeated here. That'd minimize the usage of redundant classes, however I would like to know if there's any tweaks I can apply over Firebase to access these values with ease.

But there's another issue, ie, I also need to store `head2head` values, ie the stats when two teams faced each other, since there are 20 teams, it will have 380 games and their associated stats. If I were to do this regular way,ie:

```
"Head2Head" :
{
    "M1X" : 
    {
        "Team1": 290,
        "Team2": 180,
        "Draw" : 30
    }
}
```

Which would force to create around 380 Java classes. Am I missing any common tweak that'd reduce my task in very minimal way. Is there anything I can do over Firebase to address an issue like this? Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, you need to move the "key" into the object, and give each class a "name" field.

Class 1: A `Team`.

```
"Chelsea" : 
    {
      "Counter_Attack" : 0,
      "Open_Play" : 4,
      "Penalty" : 1,
      "Set_Piece" : 0,
      "Own_goal" : 0
    },
    "Liverpool" : 
    {
      "Counter_Attack" : 0,
      "Open_Play" : 4,
      "Penalty" : 0,
      "Set_Piece" : 0,
      "Own_goal" : 0
    },
```

Becomes this for `"home"` and `"away"`

```
"home": [
   { "Name": "Chelsea", "Open_Play": 4, ...}, 
   { "Name": "Liverpool", "Open_Play": 4, ...},
   ...
]
```

---

Class 2: `Summary` looks fine.

---

Class 3: `Shot`

```
  "Arsenal" :
    {
      "Total" : 13.0,
      "OffTarget" : 5.0,
      "OnTarget" : 3.5
    },

    "Bournemouth" :
    {
      "Total" : 10.5,
      "OffTarget" : 3.5,
      "OnTarget" : 4.0
    },
```

Becomes this

```
"shots": [
   {"Name": "Arsenal", "Total": 13.0, ...}, 
   {"Name": "Bournemouth", "Total": 10.5, ...},
   ...
]
```

---

Class 4: `Passes` - same idea

---

Class 5: `Recent`

```
  "Manchester_City" :
  {
    "Game1" : 1,
    "Game2" : 1,
    "Game3" : 1,
    "Game4" : 1,
    "Game5" : 1
  },
  "Everton" :
  {
    "Game1" : 0,
    "Game2" : 1,
    "Game3" : 1,
    "Game4" : 1,
    "Game5" : 1
  },
```

The games might be better represented as a list

```
"recents": [
    {"Name": "Manchester_City", "games": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]},
    {"Name": "Everton", "games": [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]}, 
    ...
]
```